# vb.net radio button list check if selected

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following:

```
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbIsRep" runat="server"  RepeatDirection="horizontal" >
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" >Yes</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="0" >No</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

how do I check if the radiobuttonlist has any selected items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindex)  proprty to check if anything is selected and the [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem) property to get the selected item's text:

```
If rbIsRep.SelectedIndex > - 1 Then
    Dim selectedItemsText = "You selected: " & rbIsRep.SelectedItem.Text
End If
```

You can change the selection programmatically for example with the [`SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue) property.

```
rbIsRep.SelectedValue = "0"
```

or declaratively from aspx

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbIsRep" runat="server"  RepeatDirection="horizontal" >
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" >Yes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0" >No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

```cs
var hasSelection = yourRadioButtonList.SelectedIndex != -1;
```

And for VB.NET:

```vb
Dim hasSelection = yourRadioButtonList.SelectedIndex <> -1
```